# Intellij Idea debug could not access maven repo:connection refused

Tags: intellij-idea

I am starting Intellij Idea using gradle,throw this error:

```
> Could not resolve com.sportswin.soa:ws-red-envelope-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-release/com/sportswin/soa/ws-red-envelope-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-release/com/sportswin/soa/ws-red-envelope-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-release/com/sportswin/soa/ws-red-envelope-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to 127.0.0.1:7890 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I am already unset proxy in terminal:

```
# proxy list
alias proxy="export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7891"
alias unproxy="unset all_proxy"
```

unset proxy:

```
unproxy
```

and the Intellij Idea using no proxy setting, why the proxy still using `127.0.0.1:7891` when debugging?

Comment: What result do you get when running Gradle from OS terminal? If you have antivirus/firewall try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE process, IDE installation home are excluded from the scan. Also check if you have specified the proxy in custom .vmoptoins file ([Help | Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) action).

Comment: I am run gradle from terminal works fine.